# effectivness of removing triggers for temptations?

Tags: self, triggers, control

what is the  effectiveness of removing triggers for temptations (food, entertainment etc )  ?

i for example took apart the stationary (to avoid watch youtube videos for example for fun)  computer i have but after some time i reassembled it

if there wont be one attachment there would be others than even if less obvious attachments  -  can they be less bad ?

monks try to avoid this triggers as well i believe  (like asking woman to dress modest when visiting monasteries)  so i guess it has its merits

i wonder how much of a change to a practice this can make  - would love to hear general thoughts on this subject

Answer (score 1):

I find it effective.

I wrote [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/19307/254) about quitting cigarettes by not having them (and similarly a technique to help distance myself from web sites, e.g. news sites, if they become problematic).

I use a similar technique for alcohol, e.g. the easiest way for me to not have alcohol is to not buy it: if I shop once a week then I'm tempted (to buy it) no more than once a week, for maybe a minute in the day-time (when I'm in the grocery store, which sells it); and not on other days (when I don't even have it so I'm not even tempted by it) and times.

Incidentally a few days ago I found this web site https://everydaycheck.com (or you could do the same with paper, probably) which might help to create good habits. It may be better to do things as a team (e.g. meditate with a group of friends), so that social pressure (which is powerful) will encourage you to partiipate regularly; but even just having a written record helps you supervise yourself; and it records your successes not just your failures, which I find encouraging.